# How to Prevent Body Heat?

Tags: health

The Summer season is started and my body heat is increased too. Is there any way to reduce my body heat and keep it in control.

Comment: How do yo measure your increased body heat? What is your concern?

Comment: stating your locality may be of assistance. I would suggest that wearing fewer or lighter clothes might help ? You don't state what you've tried already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently moved from a country with moderate to cold climate to one that is hot all year around and I noticed that I simply wasn't consistent enough to **always** wear **flip flops/sandals and shorts**. I know is sounds so obvious, but just these two make a big difference. I also see a lot of people wearing long jeans here. And in reverse I would say: **never wear long jeans**. Super loose Pakistani style pants look alright to. Maybe you like that or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

Cold showers are good to quickly cool you down.
You could try putting a shirt in a bag into the freezer for a few hours, then wear it like the opposite of a hot water bottle

Answer (score 0):

Try to wear fresh clothing, do not ingest caffeine that will make you really active, organize your daily routes so you move or walk less, keep areas well ventilated, avoid food with high calories content, drink fresh water, coconut water is really good and refreshing, its electrolites help you rehidrate, also lemon, avoid spicy food, soak your feet in cold water.

Including some of the mentioned things in your daily routine will help you to keep your body cool or at least less hot.

Answer (score 0):

Body temperature can be regulated by cooling your blood. The simplest way to do this is to cool your hands and fore-arms where the veins come close to your skin. Rolling up your sleeves and cooling your hands with water is effective.